# How to keep ng serve active forever to keep angular2 app alive

Tags: angular

I have a angular 2 application, which i execute using  ng serve --host ip address
After executing this it gets started at default port with following logs

```
Hash: ddb0ab205ea65648a918
Version: webpack 2.1.0-beta.25
Time: 17516ms
           Asset       Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
  main.bundle.js    3.05 MB    0, 2  [emitted]  main
styles.bundle.js    10.3 kB    1, 2  [emitted]  styles
inline.bundle.js    5.53 kB       2  [emitted]  inline
        main.map    3.16 MB    0, 2  [emitted]  main
      styles.map    14.1 kB    1, 2  [emitted]  styles
      inline.map     5.6 kB       2  [emitted]  inline
      index.html  898 bytes          [emitted]
Child html-webpack-plugin for "index.html":
         Asset     Size  Chunks       Chunk Names
    index.html  3.28 kB       0
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
[default] Checking started in a separate process...
[default] Ok, 2.875 sec.
```

But after exiting this, it stops, i want to keep angular 2 app alive, can anyone suggest me how to do that.

Comment: did you find a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/).
You need to give an entry point where u create a node.js server. If you don't have it just create simple one.